# How to bind individual elements of a vue array to a class

Tags: css, vue.js

I have an array of images returned from a API in my vue component, iterated and displayed like so:

```
<span v-for="pic in pics">
   <img :src="'images/'+pic" onmouseover="highlight(pic)" :class="{isHovered = hovered}" />
</span>
```

In my script:

```
data(){
    return {
       pics: [],
       hovered: false,
    }
},
methods:{
   highlight(pic){
       this.hovered = true;
  } 
}
```

In my css

```
isHovered{
    border: 2px solid red;
    scale: 1.2;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Problem is each time I hover over an image,all the images get the isHovered class. What I intended was to bind only the image hovered on to the isHovered class.
What am i doing wrong please. Any guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm reading the OP but I can't find an answer why you can't use only CSS for that? It's a overkill to use Vue's logic for that.

```js
// thanks to @C2486 for the snippet
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      pics: [{
        img: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/qV6y1SksAcE/maxresdefault.jpg"
      }, {
        img: "http://www.memorandum.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/trunk-club-memorandum-closet-staples-chic-working-girl-professional-women-capsule-wardrobe-10.jpg"
      }, {
        img: "http://www.memorandum.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/top-working-women-career-sites-17-680x1020.jpg"
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.some-img-class:hover {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <div v-for="(pic,index) in pics">
      {{index+1}}
      <img :src="pic.img" width="60" class="some-img-class" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've done this. When you hover over an image all the images get the class.

Comment: @banky check the snippet, it only adds class for the hovered image.

Comment: @Vucko This indeed seems like the most elegant solution. Sometimes you just need to get back to the basics. One tends to get tunnel vision after using these frameworks for some time :) +1

Comment: I also thought this but I confused because of reading headline which is asking `How to bind individual elements of a vue array to a class`

Comment: @C2486 yea, the title seems misleading. If if was some non CSS event then sure, but for a simple `hover` it's a overkill. Nevertheless, Thanks for the snipper!

Comment: Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 3):

In your code you are trying to trigger hove effect for all image if any one image got hovered , Also you have syntax error to apply class. However there would be many way to achieve this, one way is like below

```js
var app = new Vue({
el:"#app",
data(){
    return {
       pics: [{img:"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/qV6y1SksAcE/maxresdefault.jpg",hovered:false},{img:"http://www.memorandum.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/trunk-club-memorandum-closet-staples-chic-working-girl-professional-women-capsule-wardrobe-10.jpg",hovered:false},{img:"http://www.memorandum.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/top-working-women-career-sites-17-680x1020.jpg",hovered:false}],
       hovered: false,
    }
},
methods:{
   
 }
});
```

```css
.isHovered{
  border:3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div>
<div v-for="(pic,index) in pics">
   {{index+1}}
   <img :src="pic.img" v-on:mouseover="pic.hovered = true" :class="{isHovered:pic.hovered}" v-on:mouseout="pic.hovered = false" width="60"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @c2486. Those pics array are generated dynamically and the length (number of images) varies depending on the product clicked from the products page. This means I have no fore-knowledge of the length of the pics array. How do I structure this?

Comment: still that would work, just on more loop to add element  `hovered:false` initially

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

That's because you have a single `hovered` property shared between all your `pics`. You need to re-write your pics so that each one has it's own `hovered` state. For example ..

```
data(){
    return {
       pics: [
          {id: 0, name: 'pic1.jpg', hovered: false},
          {id: 1, name: 'pic2.jpg', hovered: false},
          {id: 2, name: 'pic3.jpg', hovered: false},
          ...
       ]
    }
},
methods:{
   toggleHighlight(pic){
       pic.hovered = !pic.hovered;
  } 
}
```

Then in your template you can reference the individual `hovered` states ..

```
<span v-for="pic in pics">
   <img :src="'images/'+pic.name" onmouseover="toggleHighlight(pic)" :class="{isHovered: pic.hovered}" />
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks @Husam. The pics array are fetched dynamically. What I mean is this, the app is like an e-commerce app, when you click on a product it displays the single product page with the pictures uploaded for that product, so there's no way no know b4hand the number of pics that will be displayed. In this situation, how do I write my pics data pls

Comment: @banky If you could share the method wherein you fetch the pics dynamically it would help. But basically in that method you just use  `map` to add a `hovered` property to each pic before assigning the result to your `pics` array.

Comment: Just a normal axios call. Once a product is clicked on the product page, an axios call is made to the api to fetch the details of the product, including all the pictures uploaded for the product. Here I'm displaying the images and then when I mouse over anyone, I want the class to change.

Comment: @banky Okay I suppose at the end of that axios call you're assigning the response to `this.pics`. Before you do that you can do `response.map` and assign a new property `hovered` to each pic. Then you can assign the new mapped response to `this.pics`

Comment: Thanks. That sounds like what I'm looking for. I will implement it and get back to you. Thanks a million